# Minecraft from an old laptop to a new one

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

How do I get Minecraft on my new pc after buying it on my old one that got fried without having to pay for it again?

Comment: You should be able to sign into Minecraft on the website and download it again without having to pay. (I may be wrong though).

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft is account-based. Download Minecraft off [minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net) and just sign in with your account.